# two keys pressed at once in Java

Tags: java, applet, key

I'm programming a game and there 2 players play at the same time. If both players pressed a key at once and a player released his key the other player didn't move.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MultiKey extends Applet implements KeyListener {
    int x = 240, y = 240;
    int x2 = 240, y2 = 240;
    public ArrayList<Integer> keysDown;

    public void init() {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setSize(500, 500);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x2 - 50, y2 - 50, 50, 50);
        g.drawString(keysDown + "", 100, 100);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (!keysDown.contains(e.getKeyCode())) {
            keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_UP))) {
            y = y - 5;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))) {
            y = y + 5;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT))) {
            x = x - 5;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT))) {
            x = x + 5;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_W))) {
            y2 = y2 - 5;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_S))) {
            y2 = y2 + 5;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_A))) {
            x2 = x2 - 5;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_D))) {
            x2 = x2 + 5;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keysDown.remove(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Applets are deprecated, they are simple not longer supported; 2. AWT was superseded by Swing over 17 years ago (and no JavaFX); 3. The key release event may be interfering with the repeated nature of the key pressed event - a better solution, would be to use some kind of "main loop" to determine the state of the keys and update the UI accordingly

Comment: You can use Key Bindings to handle multiple key presses. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for some working examples. The `KeyboardAnimation` example code is the one you want to look at.

Comment: @camickr: Your recommendation would work for a Swing GUI but not for one that is currently 100% AWT as the OP's currently is (despite what his title says). Terrible that some institutions are still teaching AWT and applets, two extremely out-dated technologies.

Comment: I know AWT and so on is very old but we must do this in our school, by the way im from germany

Comment: Question edited: Swing removed from title -- it's misleading. Java removed -- it's not needed as you already are using the Java tag. Please be more careful with your titles and your question tags as they are the two most important parts of a question, and if you mislead you get the wrong advice (as you're seeing above).